# PHP Manipulating array values from multiple arrays into single array

Tags: php, arrays

I am fairly new to PHP and working my way through it. I've managed to solve most problems independently, but this one has had me scuppered for a while. Any help is much appreciated!

I have a series of arrays produced by a form, as follows:

```
description_array = description1, description2, description3
account_array = account1, account2, account 3
```

Where I am trying to get to is:

```
item_array = 1 => description1, account1, 2 => description2, account2
```

It may be that I am struggling with the logic more than the actual code. I've tried all sorts of manipulations with `foreach` and while loops with little success.

Any thoughts gratefully received.

Thanks
Aaron

Answer (score 3):

If the arrays are guaranteed to be balanced in size the you could do this.

```
$res = array();
for($x=0; $x<count($description_array); $x++){
       $res[] = array($description_array[$x], $account_array[$x]);
}
```

Comment: `$description_array[$i], $account_array[$i]`...`$i` should be `$x`, but other than that correct

Comment: Thank you - this works a treat (with the edit Jonathan provided)!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `key` from 1 array to get the `value` of another array:

```
$description_array = array('description1', 'description2', 'description3');
$account_array = array('account1', 'account2', 'account3');

$item_array = array();
foreach($description_array as $key=>$val){
    $item_array[] = array($val,$account_array[$key]);
}

echo '<pre>',print_r($item_array),'</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Derp. I totally misread.  And in the time it took me to fix it other people answered, but oh well. Here it is :)

```
$items = array();
foreach($description AS $k=>$v){
    if(isset($account[$k])){ 
        $items[$k] = array($v, $account[$k]); // assuming you don't really want a comma sep string, but another array.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are both equally large, it's probably simplest to iterate over one of the arrays and fill in the new array.

```
$item_array = array();
foreach ($description_array as $key => $description) {
    $item_array[$key] = array(
        'description' => $description,
        'account' => $account_array[$key]
    );
}
```

That's also easy to extend if you add further arrays.